# How do I successfully set up a rails api with serializer (using blueprint serializer) and mongo db?

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, mongodb

Trying to build a tiny rails / react / mongodb app.

Trying to hit my api end point and it's not working. I've confirmed a typical rails controller /view working properly. But I plan to add react to this app, and so I need to get a api end point working so I can send back JSON first.

controller:

```
module Api
    module V1
        class MoviesController < ApplicationController
            def index
                movies = Movie.all

                render json: MovieBlueprint.render_as_hash(movies)
            end
        end
    end
end
```

serializer:

```
class MovieBlueprint < Blueprinter::Base
    identifier(:_id)
  
    fields(
      :title,
      :description,
      :director,
      :genre,
    )
end
```

routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  namespace :api do
    namespace :v1 do
      resources :movies
    end
  end

end
```

model:

```
class Movie
  include Mongoid::Document
  
  field :title, type: String
  field :description, type: String
  field :director, type: String

end
```

sending get request to:

GET http://localhost:3000/api/v1/movies.json

output:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `_id' for #<Mongoid::Criteria
  selector: {}
  options:  {}
  class:    Movie
  embedded: false>
):

app/controllers/api/v1/movies_controller.rb:7:in `index'
```

Hoping to get back all the movies in my get request.

Comment: So I think your issue is this method [`Blueprinter::TypeHelpers#array_like?`](https://github.com/procore/blueprinter/blob/v0.25.3/lib/blueprinter/helpers/type_helpers.rb). This method checks to see if the object is an `Array` or an `ActiveRecord::Relation` however `Mongoid::Criteria` is neither so it tries to apply the blueprint to the `Mongoid::Criteria` object directly rather than iterating the objects.

Comment: To combat this it appears you could just change this `movies = Movie.all` to `movies = Movie.to_a` which will explicitly return an `Array` and thus satisfy the condition for `array_like?`